# Theming view, block id

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I've created a block in a view, but in de source code that block has the folowing id:

> block-views-Work-block_1

'Work', is the name of the view but i identifies the block by 'block_1', isn't there a way to change this to the name of the block for example?

When i see block_1 in my css file it isn't really clear what it is.

Answer (score 0):

In Views 3, you can change that under Basic Settings -> Machine Name.

It doesn't appear to be possible to change the machine name in Views 2.

Answer (score 0):

as keva says, Views 3 has the [Ability to change display ids](http://drupal.org/node/593668). if this feature is really important to you, go ahead and [install Views 3](http://drupal.org/project/views). note that the [latest release version](http://drupal.org/node/765092) is alpha quality. you might try the [6.x-3.x-dev version](http://drupal.org/node/467670), which should have more bugs fixed (but possibly also new ones introduced).